# Blocking unwanted wi-fi singnals

Tags: wi-fi

There are a lot of wi-fi connections around my phone. I want to use only one of them. Is there a way to block those unwanted connections so that they don't appear in existing connections in wi-fi settings?

Comment: You can't do that...

Comment: I want a add some wi-fi senders to black list. So they don't appear in existing wi-fi list,

Comment: You simply don't want them to show up as a potential network to connect to?  Why?  I don't know of any way to do this and I would doubt someone has come up with one, it doesn't seem useful.

Comment: I think the phone connects automatically to all wi-fis which don't have passwords.